# parallel processing multiple evaluations of a sequential task on a large data set -- a task for GPU computing?

Tags: parallel-processing, scipy, opencl, gpgpu

I am working on some signal processing code in SciPy, and am now trying to use a numerical optimizer to tune it.  Unfortunately, as these things go, it is turning out to be quite a slow process.

The operations I must perform for this optimization are the following:

- Load a large 1-d data file (~ 120000 points)
- Run optimizer, which:

  - Executes a signal processing operation, does not modify original data, produces 120000 new data points.
  - Examines difference between original signal and new signal using various operations,

    - One of which includes FFT-based convolution
    - Generates a single "error" value to summarise the result -- this is what should be minimized
  - Looks at error and re-runs operation with different parameters

The signal processing and error functions take under 3 seconds, but unfortunately doing it 50,000 times takes much longer.  I am experimenting with various more efficient optimisation algorithms, but no matter what it's going to take thousands of iterations.

I have parallelised a couple of the optimisers I'm trying using CPU threads, which wasn't too difficult since the optimiser can easily perform several scheduled runs at once on separate threads using `ThreadPool.map`.

But this is only about a 2x speed-up on my laptop, or maybe 8x on a multicore computer.  My question is, is this an application for which I could make use of GPU processing?  I have already translated some parts of the code to C, and I could imagine using OpenCL to create a function from an array of parameters to an array of error values, and running this hundreds of times at once. -- Even if it performs the sequential processing part slowly, getting all the results in one shot would be amazing.

However, my guess is that the memory requirements (loading up a large file and producing a temporary one of equal size to generate every data point) would make it difficult to run the whole algorithm in an OpenCL kernel.  I don't have much experience with GPU processing and writing CUDA/OpenCL code, so I don't want to set about learning the ins and outs if there is no hope in making it work.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to produce all 120,000 new points before analysing the difference? Could you calculate the new point, then decide for that point if you are converging?

How big are the points? A $50 graphics card today has 1Gb of memory - should be plenty for 120K points. I'm not as familiar with openCL as Cuda but there may also be limits on how much of this is texture memory vs general memory etc.

edit: More familiar with CUDA than OpenCL but this probably applies to both.
The memory on GPUs is a bit more complex but very flexible, you have texture memory that can be read by the GPU kernel and has some very clever cache features to make access to values in a 2d and 3d arrays very fast. There is openGL memory that you can write to for display and there is a limited (16-64k ?) cache per thread

Although transfers from main memory to the GPU are relatively slow ( few GB/s) the internal memory bus on the graphics card is 20x as fast as this

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I need to analyse the two vectors against each other "whole" after producing the result.  (To calculate correlation.)  The data points are double-precision, though don't necessarily have to be. 32-bit would probably give me decent results.  It's true that memory isn't expensive, but I don't really know how in CUDA or OpenCL (either is okay) you are able to allocate this memory.  From what I understand the memory model is more complex than just "malloc'ing" whatever you need, but I could be wrong. That is why I'm asking :)

Comment: I should clarify my worries about memory: it's not that I'm worried about fitting 120,000 points into 1 GB.  (120000x8 = 0.0009 GB).  Rather, I'm worried about running that algorithm thousands of times at once and each one requiring the same amount of memory, at the same time.  Anyways I guess this is one of those things I'll just have to try to see.  Even if I can only do hundreds at once it would be a huge speed-up so it may be worth it.